# How to change the button property dynamically in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

Template,

```
<div *ngFor="let detail of details"  class = "col-sm-12 nopadding">
  <a  class="button buttonaquacss button-mini button-aqua  
      text-right pull-right" [ngClass]="{activec: color}" 
      (click)='sendrequest(button,detail._id)' 
      #button [ngStyle]="{'background-color':  color}">{{buttonname}}
  </a>   
</div>
```

My ts,

```
buttonname = 'connect';
sendrequest(button, index): void {
    this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/sendrequest', formdata, { headers: headers })
        .subscribe(
        response => {
            if (response.json().status == 'success') {

                buttonname = 'pending';
                this.color = true;
            }

        });
}
```

The proflem is when I click on one button all the button properties are getting changed to pending can anyone give a suggestion please.

Comment: Could you post more code? Do you have array of buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there is only a single `buttonname` variable and all buttons bind to the same. You need to bind them to different variables. Either you use a different variable name for each button or you use an array of values.

```
<a (click)='send(button,detail._id)' #button>{{buttonname[detail._id]}}</a>
```

```
buttonname = {'id1': 'connect', 'id2': 'connect'};

sendrequest(button, index): void {
  this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/sendrequest', formdata, { headers: headers })
    .subscribe(
    response => {
        if (response.json().status == 'success') {
            buttonname[index] = 'pending';
            this.color = true;
        }
    });
}
```

**update**

```
<a (click)='send(button,detail._id)' #button>{{pendingId == detail._id ? 'pending' : 'success'}}</a>
```

```
pendingId;

sendrequest(button, index): void {
  this.pendingId = index;
  this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/sendrequest', formdata, { headers: headers })
    .subscribe(
    response => {
        if (response.json().status == 'success') {
            pendingId = null;
            this.color = true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: In future i will add mutliple names,so i want to prefer only one button

Comment: I don't understand your comment. You mentioned "all the button properties getting changed". Perhaps I misunderstood something in your question already.

Comment: Initially all my button has a name "Connect" and when i click on one of the buttons,the that button should change to "Pending" but here in my case all the button names are replaced by "pending" just for one click.

Comment: What is "one of the buttons"?

Comment: i have a loop in which i put my button,so i said on of buttons

Comment: Please add the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish to your question.

Comment: I think my answer still holds. I just added two buttons manually instead of your `*ngFor`. (I removed one).

Comment: Gunter,what does id1 and id2 mean for?

Comment: bcoz i am not not able to see the name connect in my button

Comment: `id1` and `id2` are sample `detail._id` values. You need to add one entry to `buttonname` for each id in `detail` so there is one button label for each button. If you only have two button names `connect` and `pending` there is an easier solution. I'll update my answer.

Comment: This only works if only one button can be "pending" at a time.